# Open file in C++ using int as a mode

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I ran into this code for opening file and I'm trying to understand if this line also creates a file if it doesn't exist. But I have never seen this and couldn't find it.

```
int ret = ::open(filename, 0200);
```

Can someone explain the '::' and the '0200'? 
Is this form acceptable/reasonable to use?

Thanks

Edit: I use linux x86 platform

Comment: I assume you mean [this `open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open). Why use a magic number when there are named constants listed right there?

Comment: *Is this form acceptable/reasonable to use?* No, magic constants are bad.

Comment: This is not my code, I'm just trying to understand what someone once wrote since I need to use this

Comment: As for the your other question `::` is the scope resolution operator. This is meant to disambiguate the call to `open`, in case there are overloads. Specifically, it calls the one defined in the global namespace.

Comment: @or.nomore, I understand that, but the question was *Is this form acceptable/reasonable to use?* To be honest, I didn't even notice those were octal until now, but it makes sense since those constants match the file permissions. There's one easy place for errors to slip in.

Comment: also `0200` is an octal integer literal.

Comment: @chris *Can someone explain the '::' and the '0200'?*

Comment: Without knowing the platform, it's impossible to say what `0200` was intended to mean.  For what it's worth, the standard `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, and `O_RDWR` are **not** bitwise operators.  As to whether or not it's acceptable - *you are here asking what it means*, presumably *because you can't figure it out.*  If that doesn't answer your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I have never seen this and couldn't find it.

That's a POSIX/*NIX system call - look at the man page on your local system (`man 2 open` on Linux, to make sure you get the correct section).

> Can someone explain the `::`

The `::` prefix just explicitly looks for the function at global scope, instead of any nested scope around the call site. It's useful if you have a local function, in your current namespace or class, which otherwise shadows a global function.

> ... and the '0200'?

That looks like an octal file permission for owner-write-only, but ... that doesn't match the prototype for `open`. My local Linux manpage has

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

the [open group spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) has

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

with the optional `mode_t` argument in the examples at the bottom.

Either way, this code would be passing `0200` as the flags instead of the mode; a magic number is debatable for the file mode (since many people are familiar with the octal form from the command line), but is definitely a bad choice for the flag (where the integer value of each flag is platform-specific and generally undocumented).

Note that `creat` *would* do what I suggested - creating a user-write-only file. Although, I can't think of many good reasons to create a file not even you can read back.

Alternatively, of course, your platform is non-POSIX-y enough to have an incompatible `open` function: since you haven't told us what that platform is, no-one can really help you with that.

Comment: Edited my question. My platform is linux x86

Comment: So you are calling the first version of the function, with a wholly inappropriate integer literal. Presumably it should be something like `open(filename, O_CREAT, S_IWUSR)`.